# Rails 4 - Import CSV and blank values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an ecommerce app in Rail 4. There is an import csv function to allow me to bulk upload product details. Each product has a price and a saleprice. The price is a required field. The saleprice is optional.

When I import a file with saleprice populated or not populated for new products (not on site yet), it uploads as intended. Since the saleprice field is in the hash, when it's blank, it assumes there is no saleprice. This is fine and as intended.

However, when I want to update a product that has a saleprice to remove the saleprice, then it doesn't remove the sale price. If I put the saleprice outside the hash like `:saleprice => row['SalePrice'].to_i,` then it shows saleprice as $0 (when it's blank)

When saleprice is blank, I want it to assume there is no saleprice so ignore it.

Same behavior for other fields in the list_hash

Appreciate the help.

here is the code:

```
# model
validates :saleprice, numericality: {greater_than: 0}, :allow_blank => true

def importcsv(file_path, user_id)

    open(file_path) do |f|
            CSV.parse(f.read , headers: true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|

          listing_hash = {:name => row['Product_title'], 
                          :made_to_order => row['Made_to_order'],
                          :description => row['Description'],
                          :sku => row['Product_ID'],
                          :price => row['Price'].to_i,
                          :category => row['Category'].titleize, 
                          :inventory => row['Quantity_in_stock'].to_i,
                          :image => URI.parse(row['Image']),
                          :user_id => user_id}.tap do |list_hash|
                            list_hash[:designer_or_brand] = row['Designer_or_Brand'] if row['Designer_or_Brand'] 
                            list_hash[:saleprice] = row['SalePrice'].to_i if row['SalePrice'] 
                            list_hash[:image2] = URI.parse(row['Image2']) if row['Image2'] 
                            list_hash[:image3] = URI.parse(row['Image3']) if row['Image3'] 
                            list_hash[:image4] = URI.parse(row['Image4']) if row['Image4'] 
                                end

          listing = Listing.where(sku: listing_hash[:sku], user_id: listing_hash[:user_id]) 

          if listing.count == 1 
            listing.first.update_attributes(listing_hash)
          else
            Listing.create!(listing_hash)
          end 

      end
```

Comment: Can it be that you have a space between the commas? What if you change the check to `if row['SalePrice'] && row['SalePrice'].strip.size > 0`

Comment: No, there is no space between commas. I'm trying to update a product that has a non-blank saleprice value and replacing it with a blank.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then try `row['SalePrice'].empty? ? row['SalePrice'] : row['SalePrice'].to_i if row['SalePrice']` . You will need to clean it up, but this should not set the key if value is nil, but will set it to blank if it is blank

Comment: Or you could just delete the listing if it exists and recreate each time unless you need to track create time for some reason.

Comment: @AOG Since it works fine when loading new products, I think it may have something to do with the update_attributes method towards the end of the code. Is there a different update method I should be using? The logic I use in the code is `if the sku and userid match an existing listing, then update that listing, else create it`.

Comment: @Moosa not sure if that solves your problem, but `find_or_create_by` does exactly what that the second part of ur code does. Read the docs for the method

Comment: The problem your second part of code has is that if there where clause returns more than one item (depending on whether you allow it or not, then you create a new item